# EXSLT str:replace

Tags: xslt, exslt

Im having issues getting my XML to transform correctly using the EXSLT str:replace template.

Here is my XML:

```
<XML>
<Item>
    <Field>
        <Name>ID</Name>
        <Value>98765</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>ParentID</Name>
        <Value>10002</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Type</Name>
        <Value>content</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Value>TestAPI Course</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>URL</Name>
        <Value></Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Description</Name>
        <Value>a description</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>DateBegin</Name>
        <Value>2012-04-04T00:00:00.000-07:00</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>DateEnd</Name>
        <Value>2012-04-04T00:00:00.000-08:00</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>DateCreated</Name>
        <Value>2012-04-03T00:00:00.000-07:00</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>DateModified</Name>
        <Value>2012-04-04T00:00:00.000-06:00</Value>
    </Field>
</Item>
```

Here is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" extension-element-prefixes="str" version="1.0">
        <xsl:import href="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LMSConnector\LMS\XSL\str.xsl"/>
        <xsl:template match="/Items">
            <xsl:call-template name="str:replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="Field/Name"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="search" select="ID"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="sco-id"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is that I just get a XML document header and nothing else, but nothing else? I dont think I am far off a working solution and the problems probably lie in the values i am setting for the "match" parameter on the template, and the select parameters within the call-template with-param nodes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match `<xsl:template match="/Items">`, however your XML contains `<Item>` elements, not `<Items>`.

## EDIT

---

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" extension-element-prefixes="str">
    <xsl:import href="http://delicious-library-export.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/str/str.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Item/Field/Name/text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="str:replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
          <xsl:with-param name="search" select="'ID'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'sco-id'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">      
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>      
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Item>
    <Field>
        <Name>sco-id</Name>
        <Value>98765</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Parentsco-id</Name>
        <Value>10002</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Type</Name>
        <Value>content</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Value>TestAPI Course</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>URL</Name>
        <Value/>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>Description</Name>
        <Value>a description</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>DateBegin</Name>
        <Value>2012-04-04T00:00:00.000-07:00</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>DateEnd</Name>
        <Value>2012-04-04T00:00:00.000-08:00</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>DateCreated</Name>
        <Value>2012-04-03T00:00:00.000-07:00</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
        <Name>DateModified</Name>
        <Value>2012-04-04T00:00:00.000-06:00</Value>
    </Field>
</Item>
```

Comment: Hi, I changed it to "Item" - thanks for spotting that obvious bug! Now i just get this returned: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>ID98765ParentID10002TypecontentNameTestAPI CourseURLDescriptiona descriptionDateBegin2012-04-04T00:00:00.000-07:00DateEnd2012-04-04T00:00:00.000-08:00DateCreated2012-04-03T00:00:00.000-07:00DateModified2012-04-04T00:00:00.000-06:00